# Change both checkbox text and indicator color

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to update the text color and the indicator background color based on some condition. I can get each to work individually (commented) but when I try to do both it simply uses whatever the last option is in my code i.e. either the text is changed or the indicator.

```
if True:
    self.r_eclipse_bubble_chk_bx.setEnabled(True)
    # self.r_eclipse_bubble_chk_bx.setStyleSheet('QCheckBox\
    #                                                 {\
    #                                                     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)\
    #                                                 }')
    # self.r_eclipse_bubble_chk_bx.setStyleSheet('QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked\
    #                                                 {\
    #                                                     background-color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);\
    #                                                 }')
    self.r_eclipse_bubble_chk_bx.setStyleSheet('QCheckBox {color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)};\
                                                QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked\
                                                    {\
                                                        background-color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);\
                                                    };')
else:
    self.r_eclipse_bubble_chk_bx.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
    self.r_eclipse_bubble_chk_bx.setEnabled(False)
    # self.r_eclipse_bubble_chk_bx.setStyleSheet('QCheckBox\
    #                                                 {\
    #                                                     color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)\
    #                                                 }')
    # self.r_eclipse_bubble_chk_bx.setStyleSheet('QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked\
    #                                                 {\
    #                                                     background-color : rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);\
    #                                                 }')
    self.r_eclipse_bubble_chk_bx.setStyleSheet('QCheckBox {color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)};\
                                                QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked\
                                                    {\
                                                        background-color : rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);\
                                                    };')
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc, I was currently working on providing an example but then ak22 provided the answer I needed!. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolons in the CSS markup.

Comment: This did it. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].

Comment: It helped this visitor.